# SQLite with Ionic 4? Cannot read property 'then' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, sqlite, ionic-framework, android-sqlite, ionic4

First I had [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868906/ionic-4-sqlite-typeerror-object-is-not-a-function) and I solved it. Ok, great. When I try to debug with my device (with `ionic cordova run android`). The database SQL does not loaded, it shows like has nothing or never was create the database sqlite. I check in the console and I see this:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of >undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
>      at AppComponent.push../src/app/app.component.ts.AppComponent.createDatabase >(app.component.ts:101)
>      at app.component.ts:87

In app.component.ts I have this:

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';
import { DbService } from './services/db/db.service';


rootPage: string = null;
constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private translate: TranslateService,
    private router: Router,
    private menuCtrl: MenuController,
    public DbService: DbService,
    public sqlite: SQLite
    //private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
  }

  public TableCreated = "POR EL MOMENTO NO";
  public ahora = "ahora";

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.translate.setDefaultLang('en');
      this.createDatabase();

    });
  }

  closeMenu() {
    this.menuCtrl.close();
  }

  private createDatabase(){
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default' // the location field is required
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {  <<<<----- ERROR HERE !!! but I don't know why.
      this.TableCreated = "FUE CREADA LA DB!";
      this.DbService.setDatabase(db);
      return this.DbService.createTable();
    })
    .then(() => {
      this.TableCreated = "FUE CREADA LA TABLA!";
      return this.DbService.createFirstRunningApp();
    })
    .then(() =>{
      this.TableCreated = "SE INSERTÓ LOS DATOS";
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      this.rootPage = 'HomePage';
    })
    .catch(error =>{
      console.error(error);
    });
  }
```

In db.services.ts:

```
import { SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';


export class DbService {
db: SQLiteObject = null;

  constructor() { }

 setDatabase(db: SQLiteObject){
    if(this.db === null){
      this.db = db;
    }
  }

  createTable(){
    let sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS datis(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, dati TEXT, isTrue INTEGER DEFAULT 0, dateCreated datetime default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)';
    return this.db.executeSql(sql, []);

  }

  createFirstRunningApp(){ //solo la primera vez se corre
    let allDate = [
      'Blablabla',
      'Something',
      'YellowBlueRed',
    ];
    let sql = 'INSERT INTO datis(dati) VALUES(?)';
    for (let dati of allDate) {
      this.db.executeSql(sql, [dati]);
    }
  }
}
```

this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'data.db',
      location: 'default' // the location field is required
    **}).then((db: SQLiteObject)** <--- I think this is the error, but I don't know why.

My info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.1.2 (C:\Users\Tomas\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.7
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.5
   @angular/cli               : 6.1.5
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.8
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.6

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-i
onic-webview 2.1.4, (and 4 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v8.12.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.4.1
   OS     : Windows 7
```

Any solution? For the record, I'm a beginner, maybe there's something escaping in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: This means `SQLite.create` does not return a `promise`. Don't assume that every function return promise, unless you have written it.

Answer (score 9):

```
ionic cordova platform add browser
```

and then

```
ionic cordova run browser
```

I had to run the 2nd command. With the first command, As it didn't build for me after first command. After this, it worked.

Comment: this command is also give an error like: 

Using cordova-fetch for cordova-browser@^6.0.0
Platform browser already added.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
        
        cordova platform add browser exited with exit code 1.

Answer (score 1):

Lets change your code slightly:

```
private createDatabase(){
  const conn = this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'data.db',
    location: 'default' // the location field is required
  })
  console.log('i think the db conn is undefined', conn);
  conn.then(() => {
    // etc
  })
}
```

Here, if `conn` is `undefined` then you are trying to call `undefined.then` which makes absolutely no sense. That's why you are getting the error. The real cause is that it is failing to create your db connection. That's a whole different problem. It would be easier if you changed your code as follows:

```
private createDatabase(){
  const conn = this.sqlite.create({
    name: 'data.db',
    location: 'default' // the location field is required
  })
  if (conn == null) throw Error('Failed to create database connection')
  conn.then(() => {
    // etc
  })
}
```

This catching of errors early makes code much easier to debug.

Comment: Now I get "Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Failed to create database connection
Error: Failed to create database connection". It looks like sqlite.create can't create anything. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: yup thats exactly your problem. See the error message tells you the problem now and is no longer spurious. Like I said, fixing the db problem is a whole different issue.

Comment: Not sure why you are creating a database in an Angular app, database are typically created at the backend and Angular talks to them over HTTP. Creating a database client side is like creating a db on every users machine. You prob need a shared db on a backend Node server.

Comment: If this is the case. then `catch` should execute. none of the provided solutions are working. If you reached a solution. then do share

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in my project, and it works. Try and see if it helps you.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLiteObject, SQLite } from '@ionic-native/sqlite';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class SqliteHelperService {

  private db: SQLiteObject

  constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    public sqlite: SQLite) {
  }

  
  private createDatabase(dbName?:string): Promise<SQLiteObject> {
    return this.platform.ready()
      .then((readySource: string) => {
        return this.sqlite.create({ 
          name: dbName || 'ks.db',
          location: 'default'
        }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
          this.db = db;
          return this.db;
        }).catch((error: Error) => {
          console.log('Error on open or create database: ', error);
          return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
        });  
      });  
  }

  getDb(dbName?:string, newOpen?:boolean): Promise<SQLiteObject>{
    if (newOpen) return this.createDatabase(dbName);
    return (this.db) ? Promise.resolve(this.db) : this.createDatabase(dbName);
  }  

}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try your code. And I'll let you know if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using sqlite whit angular 6 and ionic v4 too, I think the way you are returning all the object of the db is some dirty, you would execute all the interactions whit the db on the service and return only the results.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite/ngx';

@Injectable()
export class SQLiteService {

  constructor(
    private sqlite: SQLite
  ) {}

  rawQuery(queryText: string, params?: any[]): any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.sqlite.create({name: 'data.db', location: 'default'}).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        db.executeSql(queryText, params || []).then((data) => {
          resolve(data);
        }).catch(error => reject(error));
      }).catch(error => reject(error));
    });
  }
}
```